# MacFilter: incoming packet but sender mac set to our own mac address

Tags: networking

I have a problem. My antyvir Panda Internet Security has detected smart ARP type of attack. I have installed Xarp app to check if this panda's communicates are fake or so. And Panda is still shouting there is ARP attack while Xarp is not. But in the other hand when I reconnect to my WiFi network I got from Xarp app alert like this:

[image]

Is someone is trying to sniff me?

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, are you connected both to a wire and to the Wifi?

I already saw such a behavior due to the way ARP works: these are broadcast messages propagated on all ports of your router. Due to this if you broadcast something, let's say, through the Wifi interface then chances are that you will receive your own broadcast message coming back on the LAN interface (and vice versa). Some software may react a bit strangely when this occurs...

Comment: I'm connected only by WiFi.